# C++ else if char in string

Tags: c++, if-statement

title is not very informative but basically what I am trying to do is run a check against a txt file and find words that contain what i'm looking for.

The following code does it correctly and exactly how i want it to do it. BUT!

```
void qu()
{
    for (Word word : word2)
    {
        string uq = word.getWord();
        if (uq.find("qa") != std::string::npos)
        {
            cout << uq << '\n';
        }
        else if (uq.find("qb")!= std::string::npos)
        {
            cout << uq << '\n';
        }
        else if (uq.find("qc") != std::string::npos)
        {
            cout << uq << '\n';
        }
        else if (uq.find("qd") != std::string::npos)
        {
            cout << uq << '\n';
        }
        else if (uq.find("qe") != std::string::npos)
        {
            cout << uq << '\n';
        }
        else if (uq.find("qf") != std::string::npos)
        {
            cout << uq << '\n';
        }
        else if (uq.find("qg") != std::string::npos)
        {
            cout << uq << '\n';
        }
        else if (uq.find("qh") != std::string::npos)
        {
            cout << uq << '\n';
        }
        else if (uq.find("qi") != std::string::npos)
        {
            cout << uq << '\n';
        }
        else if (uq.find("qj") != std::string::npos)
        {
            cout << uq << '\n';
        }
        else if (uq.find("qk") != std::string::npos)
        {
            cout << uq << '\n';
        }
        else if (uq.find("ql") != std::string::npos)
        {
            cout << uq << '\n';
        }
        else if (uq.find("qm") != std::string::npos)
        {
            cout << uq << '\n';
        }
        else if (uq.find("qn") != std::string::npos)
        {
            cout << uq << '\n';
        }
        else if (uq.find("qo") != std::string::npos)
        {
            cout << uq << '\n';
        }
        else if (uq.find("qp") != std::string::npos)
        {
            cout << uq << '\n';
        }
        else if (uq.find("qq") != std::string::npos)
        {
            cout << uq << '\n';
        }
        else if (uq.find("qr") != std::string::npos)
        {
            cout << uq << '\n';
        }
        else if (uq.find("qs") != std::string::npos)
        {
            cout << uq << '\n';
        }
        else if (uq.find("qt") != std::string::npos)
        {
            cout << uq << '\n';
        }
        else if (uq.find("qv") != std::string::npos)
        {
            cout << uq << '\n';
        }
        else if (uq.find("qw") != std::string::npos)
        {
            cout << uq << '\n';
        }
        else if (uq.find("qx") != std::string::npos)
        {
            cout << uq << '\n';
        }
        else if (uq.find("qy") != std::string::npos)
        {
            cout << uq << '\n';
        }
        else if (uq.find("qz") != std::string::npos)
        {
            cout << uq << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to do it in a more tidy way.

If someone could point me in the right direction like a cplusplus refernce link or another documentation that would be awesome.

Comment: If an answer has actually answered your question, then please mark it as answered. Do not copy the answer into your question! That's not how Stack Overflow works...

Comment: If the code works it's more of a case of [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), which has its own site.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will perform in the same order as yours, and is a tad neater:

```
for (Word word : word2)
{
    string uq = word.getWord();
    string lookup = "qa";
    for ( char c: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
    {
        lookup[1] = c;
        if (uq.find(lookup) != std::string::npos)
        {
            cout << uq << '\n';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't just dump code; explain the problem and explain the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Replace code with data.

Create a container which contains the words you are looking for, for example a `std::set<std::string>`. Then add an inner loop which performs the `if` check for every word.

Here is an example:

```
std::set<std::string> const search_words =  { "qa", "qb", "qc", /*...*/ "qz" };
for (auto const& word : word2)
{
    std::string const uq = word.getWord();
    for (auto const& search_word : search_words)
    {
        if (uq.find(search_word) != std::string::npos)
        {
            std::cout << uq << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

The `std::set<std::string>` need not have automatic storage duration if it is always the same. You could make it a `static` data member of some class, for example.

In any case, this simple soluton will be sufficient unless you are dealing with really big data. In that case, you should find a more elaborate way from an algorithmic perspective, but that depends on how your input is actually structured.

Another possible concern *if and only if* this is performance-critical code is that a `std::set` may be little slow. I've chosen it because it guarantees that all elements are unique. But you can always replace it with a `std::vector` and see if that gains you anything.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by InternetAussie

You can put all of the strings into a vector, and use a for loop to iterate and look for each string:

```
void qu()
{
for (Word word : word2)
{
    std::string uq = word.getWord();
    std::vector<std::string> strings_to_find =
    {
        "qa", "qb", "qc", "qd", "qe", "qf", "qg", "qh", "qi", "qj", "qk",
        "ql", "qm", "qn", "qo", "qp", "qr", "qs", "qt", "qv", "qw", "qx",
        "qy", "qz"
    }; // no "qu" in original code

    for (auto& str : strings_to_find)
    {
        if (uq.find(str) != std::string::npos)
        {
            cout << uq << '\n';
        }
    }
}
}
```